# Excel - "Runtime error '1004' Method 'SaveAs' of Object' _'workbook' Failed" Macbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Trying to save a sheet as .csv on my desktop via a makro

i keep getting the "Runtime error '1004' Method 'SaveAs' of Object' _'workbook' Failed"

```
Sub Export()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht5 As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
   
Set sht5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ExportCsv")               'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    
sht5.Copy Before:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1

If Cells(r, 10) = 0 Then

Rows(r).Delete

End If
        
Next r

Application.DisplayAlerts = False                             'Possibly overwrite without asking
wb.SaveAs Filename:="/Users/thomasduus/Desktop/1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a invalid address. You are missing the `C\` (or reference to your root drive) and your slashes are backwards

Comment: Is that a valid path? You could always try recording a macro to generate the correct one.

Comment: Im running on a Mac - The path should be valid.

Comment: I thought mac used `:` as the separator?

Comment: Using `:` stops the display of The Runtime Error box, it seems like it goes thru the entire process, but it dosent overwrite the preexcisting 1.csv file on my desktop

Comment: Your code works for me using O365 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Which versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mac file location works something like:

```
Wb.SaveAs "Macintosh HD:Users:thomasduus:Desktop:1.csv"
```

Comment: Using `:` and the path you suggested stops the display of The Runtime Error box, it seems like it goes thru the entire process, but it dosent overwrite the preexcisting 1.csv file on my desktop :( ?

Comment: Yea - that’s about the extent of my Mac specific VBA knowledge. Add Mac tag to your question so maybe someone with more experience there will be incentivized to look at your question!

Comment: You could just open the original and edit that so you don’t have to worry about the problem of overwriting

Comment: Try saving it under a different name just to make sure the saveas code is working. You turned off alerts which is the correct way to do that so must be a Mac specific issue and I don’t have one with excel so can’t test/help much there. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Your file path is incorrect, possibly the drive is C: so add C: in front and use backslashes. Corrected line:

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\thomasduus\Desktop\1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: I thought this too but this is not valid for mac which OP is using